# SEM: Robust estimation in Onyx

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, structural-equation-modeling, multivariate-normal-distribution

Does anyone know if there is a possibility for **robust estimation** (e. g. Yuan-Bentler or Satorra-Bentler) in **Onyx**, because the normal distribution assumption is not given? I only see the options Maximum Likelihood and Least Squares.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is a possibility for robust estimation (e. g. Yuan-Bentler or Satorra-Bentler) in Onyx, because the normal distribution assumption is not given? I only see the options Maximum Likelihood and Least Squares.

No, I do not believe they are available, though it's not too much of as surprise as "`Ωnyx` is intended to be a teaching tool" (von Oertzen, Brandmaier, Tsang, 2013) and was not designed to replace other software available at the time, such as `Mplus` and `EQS`. This is not only made clear in the [user's manual](https://ww.statpower.net/Content/319SEM/Reading/Onyxuserguide.pdf) (Von Oertzen, Brandmaier, Tsang, 2013)$^1$ , but also in other publications (e.g., von Oertzen, Brandmaier, & Tsang, 2015).

For more information on software implementations of robust corrections to SEM test statistics, I highly recommend Bryant & Satorra (2012) and Savalei (2014).

$^1$ Note however that the manual is very much outdated, as noted on the [Ωnyx website](https://onyx-sem.com/documentation/).

**References**

Bryant, F. B., & Satorra, A. (2012). Principles and practice of scaled difference chi-square testing. Structural equation modeling: A multidisciplinary journal, 19(3), 372-398.

Savalei, V. (2014). Understanding robust corrections in structural equation modeling. Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 21(1), 149-160.

von Oertzen, T., Brandmaier, A. M., & Tsang, S. (2013). Ωnyx user guide.

von Oertzen, T., Brandmaier, A. M., & Tsang, S. (2015). Structural equation modeling with Ωnyx. Structural Equation Modeling: A Multidisciplinary Journal, 22(1), 148-161.